# Fake invoice attachments, what's the real functionality doing?

Tags: virus, macros, malware, attachments

Over the last few months I've been receiving about 10 emails per day containing fake invoices, e.g.

> Good Morning
>
> The order below was sent over 28/05/15 (please do not duplicate).  I
>   am still waiting for delivery on line 002 for 18 pieces
>
> Please could you advise when delivery will be as we need the goods
>   urgently
>
> Thanks

Obviously this is junk/malware, but strangely, none of my anti-virus/malware products on any machine (Trend and Bitdefender) acknowledge them as a threat.

I reported the file to Bitdefender, and never even got a response.

It appears [others](https://techhelplist.com/index.php/spam-list/817-self-bill-attached-malware) have concerns too.  I inspected the file in Notepad and could see some VBA code, so I assume its a macro, which I would expect in a Word document.  [TechHelpList.com](https://www.virustotal.com/uk/file/3a1cd4d19bd7e366994eab61f2d6402e12d5720ca1cd29a788c9a72b51b71bfa/analysis/) states that the file tries to download an .EXE but the information is vague.

Given the quantity of these, I assume they are all of a similar nature, but can anyone offer some explanation as to exactly what the file tries to accomplish?  Is the EXE embedded, or does it try to download?  In the case of the latter, does Word actually warn you, or offer the option not to run the Macro?

I have Office 2013, so would assume macros in .doc file won't automatically run, but I'm trying to convince my IT-phobe friends and family not to go near them.

Comment: Without telling us what the code is, how could we help you? Open it in a virtual sandbox if you want to know.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing, I wouldn't suggest even that, virtual machines and virtual sandboxes are not bullet proof.  If the same host is sending you the spam, block all email, from that provider at your firewall.

Comment: I've had similar, also passing virus scans. I treated it as malware nonetheless, though it may simply have been an advertisement. Whichever it was, I marked it as spam and hope that future e-mails like this will go to spam automatically.

Comment: If you look at the Virus Total page again there are some comments there which link to a blog post from Sane Security about exactly this sort of thing: http://sanesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/rachelhopkinson-anixtercom-212-b59329.html. Bascially the VBA in the invoice attempts to download an exe file with malware called Dridex which is designed to steal all kinds of information.

Comment: @Raystafarian yes sorry.  I did upload but forgot to include a link.  It's there now alongside the file name.

Comment: @James +1 thanks for the link.  It is with HUGE irony that Bitdefender blocks the forum page from opening...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen similar fake invoices myself - again, on inspection in an isolated VM - the macros try to execute a remote .exe or .bat file.  They may or may not auto-run - its dependant on your macro security settings within word/excel/etc...

You will find that your antivirus will block the .exe (hyopefully) when it is called or loaded, but the invoice itself isn't malicious by an AVs definition, because all it is doing is opening another file.

Its no different to a file having a macro which opens an external application such as paint, calculator, notepad etc - it's not the file which causes the damage, but the exe it opens.

AV is smart, but generally not smart enough to read/analyse code and then follow links outside to the remote exe and scan that as well.

As for what they do - it can be anything - the limit is only what a programmer can dream up.  Common virus' carried by these types of executables include:

- Ransomwear (See [this article](https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/mmpc/shared/ransomware.aspx) for an example)
- Service edits (replace a vital windows service with a modified copy which snoops on your activity and reports back to the creator somewhere)
- Malware installation (install a silent remote control application so a user can mes with your PC)
- Key logging (sends a list of every key stroke back to the creator.. including your passwords!)
  ..the list can be virtually limitlless

What can you do to prevent yourself?

- Keep windows/applicatiosn up to date and fully patched
- Regularly scan with fully updated antivirus/antispyware/antimalware
- Don't ever open attachments unless working in a sandboxed VM
- Keep good backups so you can just go for a complete wipe if infected
- Don't ever open attachments in general unless you are expecting them.  Delete them immediately.  If it later turns out that it was a genuine attachment, they can always be sent again

Comment: fair point, will update answer

Comment: Good answer, thanks.  I don't have access to a sandbox environment, so was posting here in the hope that somebody might share what happens when the file is opened.  Pretty grim job I know, but I was hoping it could increase awareness for others.  What I am interested to know is whether the macro just downloads and runs the EXE without any warning, e.g. a seamless process.  Or whether its not actually a VBA affair after all...

Comment: could be either... without a copy of the code, I couldn't give you a definitive answer.  Generally, you'll find it'll silently execue a program run under your (probably) administrator account and do all sorts to your machine

Comment: File link has been added just in case anyone's feeling "adventurous"

Comment: Not a smart idea... linking to a known virus is a sure fire way to annoy a moderator... or accidentally infect/spread a virus.  I've edited it out.